# Is there a shortcut to add bullet points with markdown in RStudio?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rstudio, r-markdown

I know that it's possible to add comments in RStudio fairly easy by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Is there a way to do the same thing, but that it's going to add a bullet list instead of "`#`"?

I have a long list and don't want to manually add `*` because it would be too long and prone to errors.

Comment: you could use ctrl+alt+arrows to make a multiple selection of all lines, and then add a *

Comment: Brilliant!! That solved my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@scoa solved the problem!

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up arrows</kbd> or <kbd>down arrows</kbd>. It extent your cursor so that you can input multiple characters at the same time.